# Adding Firebase Analytics to Instant App

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, android-instant-apps

I am converting my existing application to Android Instant App. I have successfully done that. My app is running in Instant App form. The issue that I am facing now is regarding Firebase-Analytics. When I run instant app I get this error

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
```

When i try to get `FirebaseAnalytics` instance using `FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);` the instant app crashes. I am not able to get any sort of logs on `Logcat`. My "Installed" app is working perfectly fine. Also if someone can guide me on how to debug Instant Apps, I am not able to debug them or even get logs on Logcat.

**Edit**
Link to [Bug Report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71335307)

Comment: Can you try passing ApplicationContext instead of `this`? For debugging, make sure your debug build configuration has `debuggable true` and then you can add a breakpoint and click on Debug button beside Run button on toolbar in Android Studio.

Comment: @adnanyousafch no luck, still getting crash and cant debug either

Comment: Can you open the merged manifest of the instant app and see if there is an issue with manifest merging?

Comment: Please check the guide for adding Firebase Analytics to AIA and make sure you have followed it in your existing app: https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/guides/analytics.html#adding_google_analytics_to_an_instant_app_project
Also, I would suggest you to refer to AIA analytics sample application: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/analytics
I hope this will help.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh, Incase the problem is still not solved, I would suggest you to file a bug and see if Google can assist you. Also, please share link to your bug back in here so it would be helpful for all. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787
TIP: Google might need sample project/Instant Application (with this issue) to provide a quick solution.

Comment: @PragatiSingh great I will file a bug report. Thank you.

Comment: @Atif Farrukh, i hope you have reported this to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787 please can you mention that link here as well.

Comment: @PragatiSingh I'm really sorry, I got busy in some other stuff and completely forgot about this. I will create a sample app today and will check if the issue persists, if it does I'll report the bug and update here. If its solved, I'll still update the post. Again sorry.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh I hope you have reported bug there or it has been solved.

Comment: @PragatiSingh yes I have posted it there; https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71335307
The issue was, i was having Google Play Services for Instant Services v 1.22.. after updated that it was resolved.

Comment: @AtifFarrukh, can you accept answer here as well. Thanks for your support and information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Google Play services for Instant Apps 2.7-release-179555567**

With Reference to [Google issue tracker](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71335307)

Your Google Play services for Instant Apps version is 1.22...

If you update to the latest, **it should be fixed with: 2.7+**

1. Uninstall Google Play services for Instant Apps
2. Go back to Settings > Google > Instant Apps
3. It will ask you to restore it > RESTORE
4. Now try running your instant app again.

If you are experiencing this while trying to build your instant app from Android Studio, you may have to repeat steps 1-4 one more time. On first provisioning, it may install your device with the incorrect version (1.22...), but afterwards, it should be the correct version.

*That solved my problem but will users always have the latest Google Play services for Instant Apps (i.e. 2.7+)? As I didn't side load Google Play services for Instant Apps or was it installed by Android Studio?*

**Ans:-**
Yes, users on pre-O should be periodically pushed the latest Google Play services for Instant Apps. Plus, they can always perform steps 1-3 to make sure they get the latest.

On O+, they shouldn't have to do anything either, since Instant Apps support is built directly into the framework from here on out.

Working with the OEMs, Google Play services for Instant Apps have been pushed to all devices which have been deemed compatible for Instant Apps. The other case is where Android Studio installs it when you try to build your instant app to a whitelisted device.