# Firebase analytics for instant app

Tags: android, firebase-analytics, android-instant-apps

I am getting the following error while applying firebase analytics integration

```
02-21 17:32:59.447 12786-12786/? E/FA: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing google app id value from from string resources with name google_app_id.
    02-21 17:32:59.447 12786-12786/? E/FA: Scheduler not set. Not logging error/warn
    02-21 17:32:59.535 12786-12837/? E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
```

Setup Details is as follow:

Base Module:

```
added google-services.json to base module.
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
api "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${MOBILE_GMS_LIBRARY_VERSION}"
api 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

App Module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47131986/adding-firebase-analytics-to-instant-app

Comment: please can you check https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/guides/analytics.html#adding_google_analytics_to_an_instant_app_project and https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/analytics might it help you.

Comment: Ensure you are using `v3.1.0` or higher of the `google-services` plugin.  
   `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'`

Comment: @PragatiSingh I already tried the possible duplicate solution. let me try 3.1.1.

Comment: Still not working

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34365369/googleservice-failed-to-initialize ?

Comment: @PragatiSingh Still not resolved

Comment: Can you file a bug to Google, then link to it back in here? It would be helpful for all, thanks! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Answer (score 2):

add to strings.xml

```xml
<string name="google_app_id">x:xxxxxx:android:xxxx</string>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please add more information to your answer, like how it fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
02-21 17:32:59.535 12786-12837/? E/FA: Missing google_app_id. Firebase Analytics disabled.
```

I think this is the exception, to resolve this, try to enable Firebase Analytic in your Firebase Project, and then download the newest Google.json file according to your package file then applied it on your Android project.

Comment: Enable mean plz? I am already using base package and google.json for the same.

Comment: you can check the sample here
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/analytics

Answer (score 0):

[Google Issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73783836)

Good news! The engineers have fixed Gradle sync failure issue in version `3.2.1` of **google-services**.

I verified that project provided in comment#3 could be successfully 
compiled with '`com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1`'.